# Проверка корректности времени

Tags: php, функции

Есть в php функция проверки корректности даты - `checkdate($month, $day, $year)`

Мне нужно проверить корректность времени, чтобы отсеивать несуществующие варианты или строки вообще временем не являющиеся. Есть ли в php функция подобная `checkdate`, но для времени или для `datetime`?

Сам не нашел, начал писать проверку, вижу что все очень простенько и громоздко, закралась мысль что есть способ красивее.

Comment: а проверить регулярками строку на подобность шаблону?

Comment: Что на входе может быть? Если по аналогии, проверить просто два числа, то не вижу проблемы. А если все варианты подряд, включая `5am`, `16-45`, `16:45`, `16 45` — надо обозначить валидные варианты более чётко.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[strtotime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

> Returns a timestamp on success, FALSE
> otherwise

```
$times = array
(   
    '15:43', '4 hours 2 seconds', '5am',
    '25:88', '1 hour 61 seconds', '0pm'
);

foreach( $times as $time )
{
    echo "$time :: ".(strtotime( $time ) === false ? 'BAD' : 'OK')."\n";
}
```